# Real Time Updates story id

Tags: facebook, comments, real-time, feed

I managed to get the real time updates to work on pages. I am now just wondering, if there is an easy way to get the comment or story (the comment was posted on) which fired the request to my server? For now I just receive the ID (even twice as id and uid) of the page the comment/story was posted to. I have set 'include_values' to true when creating the subscription.

It would be easy to find the latest story posted by getting the Feed of the page, but for the comments it is absolutely not that easy.
The easiest way would be to receive the story id (or even the comment id), is there any way to tell Facebook to do so? Or can I get the latest comments posted to any story of the page with the Graph API?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

As there does not seem to be a way to receive the story id, I implemented this by running through the feed and getting the latest updated story.. Not very beautiful, but works somehow.
Only Problem I am having now is, that if a user posts a new story to the wall the id AND the uid is the id of the user, not of the page. So I would have to run through every feed of every page connected to the application and find the story. Impossible...

Comment: This should be added to the question and not posted as an answer.